# pine script sum function returns only float I need integer

Tags: sum, pine-script

I made simple variable
and i want to count how many times it occur

so I made code like this

```
a = close>open(it is just examplary, not my real code)


gross = ~~~~~~

num = cum(a ? 1 : 0)


total = sum(a ? gross : na, num)
```

I put the num variable into length position of sum function

but it turns error message like this

```
cannot call 'sum' with 'length'=series[float]. the argument should be of type: series[integer];
```

so to check the value of num is float, I made `plot(num,~~)` and it returns 128.0000

I think condition a occured 128times.

so the value of num isn't float am i right?
I don't know why error message happens

I already used `round()` and `int()
please help me solve this problem

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.